# Notify Activity Class

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-messaging

I have 2 classes which are GcmMessageHandler and Control (its an activity class, shows some graphics). When i handle the gcm message, i want to refresh control class (but if its front)

```
public class GcmMessageHandler extends IntentService {

            String mes;
            private Handler handler;
            public GcmMessageHandler() {
                super("GcmMessageHandler");
            }

            @Override
            public void onCreate() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onCreate();
                handler = new Handler();
            }
            @Override
            protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
               Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

               GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);
               // The getMessageType() intent parameter must be the intent you received
               // in your BroadcastReceiver.
               String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);

               mes = extras.getString("title");
               showToast();
               Log.i("GCM", "Received : (" +messageType+")  "+extras.getString("title"));

               GcmBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);

            }

            public void showToast(){
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        if(mes.equals("Control")){

                        }else{
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),mes , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                 });

            }
        }
```

In this part:

```
if(mes.equals("Control")){ }
```

if the control activity class is resume, i want to refresh it. How can i do this?

Comment: I'm not sure it is possible the way you imagine it : either you update your graphics inside that activity or you have to restart the whole activity.

Comment: @Zakaria i want to notify mainactivity from gcm message. But i dont know how to refresh it without restart

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `BroadcastReceiver` in order to notify your activity about any changes. So register a `BroadcastReceiver` in your activity first:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public static String REFRESH_ACTIVITY = "com.domain.action.REFRESH_UI"

    private BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            // do UI updates
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        // do UI updates

        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction(REFRESH_ACTIVITY);
        this.registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, filter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        this.unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);
    }

    ...
}
```

Then send the broadcast to perform the UI update from any location:

```
if (mes.equals("Control")) { 
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(MainActivity.REFRESH_ACTIVITY);

    sendBroadcast(intent);
}
```

Comment: sorry, i couldnt understand. i want to refresh MainActivity (class). Should i create another class ControlActivity or implement in MainActivity. Last question; what i should write instead of "com.domain.action.REFRESH_UI" (my package name is com.test.argeproject)

Comment: Then use `MainActivity` instead (see updates above); add the `BroadcastReceiver` member and (un-)register it in `onResume`/`onPause` as shown above. Send a broadcast using the example below in order to trigger the `onReceive()` method. The String is self defined - you could use any other unique String (e.g. `"com.test.argeproject.my_refresh"`).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use an observer design pattern. 
Let the GcmMessageHandler hold the Control activity as an observer and then notify it when needed.

```
public class GcmMessageHandler extends IntentService {

        String mes;
        private Handler handler;
        private Control mObserver

        public GcmMessageHandler() {
            super("GcmMessageHandler");
        }

        public void attachObserver(Control ctrl) {
            mObserver = ctrl;
        }
```

Then you just add a method to the Control class that can be called from the GcmMessageHandler class.

```
   if(mes.equals("Control")){
           mObserver.update(); // example
                        }else ...
```

It would be more slick if you first defined an observer interface:

```
public interface IObserver {
    public abstract void update();
}
```

and had your Control class implement that. This way your GcmMessageHandler class could have a list of observers:

```
   public class GcmMessageHandler extends IntentService {

        String mes;
        private Handler handler;
        private List<IObserver> mObservers;

        public GcmMessageHandler() {
            super("GcmMessageHandler");
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onCreate();
            handler = new Handler();
            mObservers = new ArrayList<IObserver>();
        }

        public void attachObserver(Control ctrl) {
            mObservers.add(ctrl);
        }
        private void notify() {
         for(IObserver observer : mObservers) 
            observer.update();
        }
```

And of course if the Control class is the one holding the GcmMessageHandler object your just call the attach method from Control like this:

```
myGcmMessageHandler.attachObserver(this);
```